# javascript hide toggle using a class, or direct hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

What is more correct, and has better performance:
I have a  container with elements in it. Based on the button clicked I need to show/hide elements. Example:

```
<div id="panel">
   <button id="toggle-edit">Edit</button>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

now, what is better:
1) Using one class and some CSS rules:

```
#panel .form-group {display: none}
#panel.show-inputs .form-group {display: block}
```

And a simple JS:

```
$("#toggle-edit").click(function() {
   $("#panel").toggleClass("show-inputs") 
});
```

2) Using plain JS, no css classes:

```
$("#toggle-edit").click(function(){
   $("#panel .form-group").toggle();
   // I might want toggle this.value = "Cancel"/"Edit" as well
});
```

Is it technically good to use CSS class on a parent element to affect child elements visibility?

Comment: *"and has better performance"* - I don't think you're going to have a user-perceivable performance difference here.

Comment: I know, just curious about that. the CSS rules way seems like "let the browser do his job", while the JS way is specifically selecting the elements and tell the browser "hide these", so just wonder from the browser perspective

Answer (score 2):

Here I built a tool to benchmark execution time for both methods.

Calling both methods 250 times and measuring milliseconds taken.

In my tests...

*Class toggle took* `7 to 10 milliseconds` to run 250 times

*jQuery toggle took* `88 to 110 milliseconds` to run 250 times

Feel free to run them in the snippet below yourself ;)

```js
toggleClass = function() {
  $("#panel").toggleClass("show-inputs")
};
$("#toggle-class").click(toggleClass);

jQueryToggle = function() {
  $("#panel-jquery .form-group").toggle();
};

$("#toggle-hide").click(jQueryToggle);

// Demo first run
benchmark('start');
benchmark();

function benchmark(start) {
  var d = new Date();
  var ms = 1000 * 60 * d.getMinutes() + 1000 * d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds();
  if (start) {
    this.initTime = ms
  } else {
    var timeTaken = ms - this.initTime;
    delete this.initTime;
    return timeTaken;
  }
}

function bench250() {
  var classTime, jqToggleTime;
  benchmark('start');
  for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
    toggleClass();
  }
  classTime = benchmark()

  benchmark('start');
  for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
    jQueryToggle();
  }
  jqToggleTime = benchmark()
  $(".results").append('<tr><th>' + classTime + '</th><th>' + jqToggleTime + '</th></tr>');
}


$(".test250").click(bench250);
```

```css
#panel .form-group {
  display: none
}
#panel.show-inputs .form-group {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class='results' width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <td><h2>Test results</h2></td>
    <td><button class='test250'>Test 250 times</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Class Toggle</th>
    <th>jQuery Toggle</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="panel">
  <h2>Toggle class</h2>
  <button id="toggle-class">Toggle Class</button>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="panel-jquery">
  <h2>jQuery Toggle</h2>
  <button id="toggle-hide">jQuery toggle()</button>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its not about performance but its about [reusability of code](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/)

So using class will help you in reuse your code.

Comment: *"So using class will help you in reuse your code."* - Wouldn't it be easier to reuse *without* the class, because then you can just copy the relevant JS and change the selector without having to coordinate style-sheet changes too?